# Why does a set of m elements have 2$^m$ subsets?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, elementary-set-theory, proof-writing, computer-science, relations

**Note:** This example is from Discrete Mathematics and Its Applications [7th ed, prob 2, pg 576], shout out to @crash.

[image]

I understand why $A \times A$ has $n^2$ elements(because every member of set $A$ can form a combination with itself and every other element of $A$. Can someone explain the mathematical intuition of how a set with $m$ elements has  $2^m$ subsets?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A element in the set can be either included or not in the subset. So you have 2 possibilities for each element, which equals $2^m$ possibilities, or subsets

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:** how many subsets of $0$ elements does $A$ have? How many subsets of $1$ element? How many subsets of $m$ elements? $$2^m = (1+1)^m = \sum_{k=0}^m {m \choose k}.$$

Comment: A textbook combinatorial proof of the binomial theorem for $1+1$ is by arguing there are $2^m$ subsets of a set of size $m$, so this could be circular depending on how one wants to organize the facts.

Comment: Well, yes, but one can always prove the binomial theorem by induction, and make this argument valid. `:)`